# Three tables SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (Vehicles) which contains a list of vehicles.

```
VehicleID
PlateNo
CurrentDriver
```

I also have a table (History) which contains a the driver history for the vehicles:

```
HistoryID
VehicleID
ReceivedDate (vehicle receiving date)
DriverName
```

I have another table (Repairs) which contains the repairs for all the vehicles:

```
RepairID
VehicleID
RepairDate
RepairCost
```

Using SQL Server and based on the History table, I want to get all the RepairCost values between two dates for a given DriverName.

For example, I want to get all the RepairCost values for driver 'John Doe', between 01.01.2013 and 01.05.2013, who was allocated to three different vehicles in that period.

My query so far is:

```
SELECT H.DriverName, R.RepairCost, R.RepairDate
  FROM Repairs AS R 
 INNER JOIN Vehicles AS V ON R.VehicleID = V.VehicleID 
 INNER JOIN History H ON H.VehicleID = V.VehicleID 
 WHERE H.DriverName = 'John' 
   AND R.RepairDate BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '04.01.2013'
```

There's also some sample data in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcebf/3).

The problem seems to be that I'm getting all the results twice.

LATER EDIT:
My progress so far:

```
DECLARE @Driver varchar(50),@StartDt datetime, @EndDt datetime

SELECT @Driver = 'John Doe',@StartDt = '20130101' ,@EndDt = '20130501'

;With VehicleAllocation
AS
(
SELECT h.*,h1.ChangeDate
FROM History h
OUTER APPLY (SELECT MIN(ReceivedDate) AS ChangeDate
FROM History
WHERE VehicleID = h.VehicleID
AND DriverName <> h.DriverName
AND ReceivedDate > h.ReceivedDate
)h1
WHERE h.DriverName = @Driver
)
SELECT *
FROM VehicleAllocation h
INNER JOIN Repairs r
ON r.VehicleID = h.VehicleID
WHERE DriverName = @Driver
AND RepairDate > = @StartDt
AND RepairDate < @EndDt + 1
AND RepairDate BETWEEN h.ReceivedDate AND COALESCE(h.ChangeDate,RepairDate)
```

I discoverd a problem with the line 'AND DriverName <> h.DriverName'. Why is that line useful? If I had the same driver name, one after the other, in the History table, it skipped to the last car delivery date for that driver name.

Sample data:

'History' table

```
ReceivedDate  DriverName
04.11.2013    Mike
13.11.2013    Dan
15.11.2013    Dan
17.11.2013    Ryan
20.11.2013    Dan
22.11.2013    Ryan
25.11.2013    Mike
26.11.2013    Dan
29.11.2013    Ryan
04.12.2013    Dan
```

'Repairs' table

```
RepairDate RepairCost
05.11.2013 2615.30
14.11.2013 135.66
16.11.2013 4913.04
18.11.2013 538.92
21.11.2013 152.48
23.11.2013 5946.89
26.11.2013 3697.64
27.11.2013 734.01
30.11.2013 279.62
```

Query result

```
RepairDate RepairCost
07.11.2013 380.00
14.11.2013 135.66
16.11.2013 4913.04
16.11.2013 4913.04
21.11.2013 152.48
27.11.2013 734.01
```

As you can see in the query result, line 3 and 4 have the same value/date.
The query interval was 01-01-2013 <-> 31-12-2013.

Also, what if I want to get the SUM of different colums from different tables?
For example, SUM(Total) column from 'Repairs' table, SUM(Value) column from 'Tires' table...

How can I adapt the script?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your attempted query? What errors are you getting? Is the result different from expected?

Comment: I've used SQL Fiddle to show you my query, so far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcebf/3

Comment: It seems that the results are doubled.

Comment: Do you know about [DISTINCT](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/distinct.php)?

Comment: I know about DISTINCT, but I want to get all the values from Repair table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea why you include you Vehicle table in your query, as you don't want any information from there.

You are getting "double" results because you match every Repair (e.g. the one on jan 15th) with every record with the same Vehicle id is History (there are three of those!). Two of those matches are for drive John, so you get two results.

What you want is to match only on the driver that, according to your history table, was the drive at the time of the repair!

So, I first matched each repairdate with the actually matching Receiveddate in the history table:

```
SELECT R1.Repairdate, Max(H1.ReceivedDate) as ReceivedDate
FROM Repairs R1
JOIN History H1 
  ON R1.VehicleID=H1.VehicleID 
 AND H1.ReceivedDate < R1.RepairDate
```

GROUP BY R1.RepairDate

I then used that query in a join to receive the wanted data:

```
SELECT R.RepairDate, H.DriverName, R.RepairCost 
  FROM Repairs AS R 
  JOIN History H ON R.VehicleID=H.VehicleID 
  JOIN (
       SELECT R1.Repairdate, Max(H1.ReceivedDate) as ReceivedDate
         FROM Repairs R1
         JOIN History H1 
           ON R1.VehicleID=H1.VehicleID 
          AND H1.ReceivedDate < R1.RepairDate
        GROUP BY R1.RepairDate) 
        AS H2
    ON R.Repairdate = H2.Repairdate
   AND H.ReceivedDate = H2.Receiveddate
 WHERE R.RepairDate BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '04.01.2013' 
   AND H.DriverName = 'John'
```

This returns me 6 records : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcebf/62

As a sanity check, leave out the complete `WHERE` on date and name and include the vehicle number in teh select.

You will get 14 repairs listed with the name of the driver who was drivign the vehicle at that time. You can easily confirm that the driver linked to the vehicle at that time is correct according to your History data:

```
DRIVERNAME  VEHICLEID   REPAIRDATE  REPAIRCOST
John    1   January, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000  10
Ryan    2   January, 18 2013 00:00:00+0000  15
Ryan    2   January, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000  15
John    1   February, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 5
Ryan    2   February, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 25
John    1   February, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000 10
John    2   February, 26 2013 00:00:00+0000 10
Ryan    1   March, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000    100
John    2   March, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000    30
John    2   March, 08 2013 00:00:00+0000    5
Ryan    1   March, 10 2013 00:00:00+0000    45
Ryan    1   March, 17 2013 00:00:00+0000    25
Ryan    2   March, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000    10
Ryan    2   March, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000    30
```

Comment: Thanks, oerkelens. I've added the Vehicle table because I want to get by plate number, the sum of different costs from different tables by vehicle. That's the second part of the question. I've added a GROUP BY H.VehicleID but it only works for the Repairs table. How do I do that? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcebf/70

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your `sum from more tables` as i only see costs in 1 table... I think if you want totals per `vehicle`, you should use a different query - this one gives you the costs per driver. Unless you want costs per driver per vehicle, in which case you can indeed group by vehicleID. But your other costs from other tables are not that easy to add i think. Maybe better to formulate that in a new question :)

Comment: The database has other tables, similar to the Repairs table, which also contain costs (Tires table, Insurance table,..) I want to generate a report that contains total values from this tables also per driver, not per vehicle. How can I adapt the query you provided, for this purpose.. The end report should contain (per given driver and period), the following columns: Vehicle's number|Total repair cost|Total tire cost|...

Comment: You will have to link them (provided they have a date every time) to the history table in a similar way. That will make for a very complicated query - you might consider creating a udf that gives you the drivers name for a vehicle at a given date instead, you could even add that as a non-persisted computed column to your repair (and other tables), which would your queries much easier :)

Comment: I've never used a udf before.. I think the H2 part of the query could be a function. I've tried some querys but I get errors :( How to define a function that returns a table?

Comment: My function that shoul return a table, but it doesn't work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcebf/71

Answer (score 0):

if you add HistoryID to your query you will notice that rows are not duplicate, but they have different HistoryID, try this query

```
SELECT H.DriverName, R.RepairCost, R.RepairDate , H.HistoryID
FROM
    Repairs AS R
    INNER JOIN Vehicles AS V ON R.VehicleID=V.VehicleID
    INNER JOIN History H ON H.VehicleID=V.VehicleID 
WHERE H.DriverName='John' AND R.RepairDate BETWEEN '01.01.2013' AND '04.01.2013'
```

so I think it's something wrong with your data.

you can eliminate these duplicate rows using `DISTINCT` , but I recommend you to double check your History table data