# SQL function create error - "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, database-table

I'm trying to create this function which returns a table and has a table name as a parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCostData(@CostTable VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS @H2 TABLE (
    Repairdate    datetime     NOT NULL,
    ReceivedDate  datetime     NOT NULL
)  
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @H2(DataFactura, Data)
      SELECT R1.Repairdate, Max(H1.ReceivedDate) as ReceivedDate
        FROM @CostTable R1
        JOIN History H1 
        ON R1.VehicleID=H1.VehicleID 
        AND H1.ReceivedDate < R1.RepairDate
        GROUP BY R1.RepairDate;
    RETURN;
END;
```

But I get 'Must declare the scalar variable "@CostTable".' error. Why? How can I fix it?

Comment: `CostTable ` is `VARCHAR`, you might want to use dynamic sql.

Comment: You cannot use dynamic SQL in functions, I think... You will need to change that into a stored proc.

Comment: beware of what you are doing. Generic functions like that, especially if you use them in another SELECT, will drain performances. Sometimes, in SQL, it is better to copy/paste code

Comment: Thanks, but I can't turn it into a SP, because I'm using it in a query.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the DECLARE @CostTable statement

Try this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetCostData(@CostTable VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS @H2 TABLE (
    Repairdate    datetime     NOT NULL,
    ReceivedDate  datetime     NOT NULL
)

AS

BEGIN 
DECLARE @CostTable table (RepairDate datetime not null) 
    INSERT INTO @H2(DataFactura, Data)
      SELECT R1.Repairdate, Max(H1.ReceivedDate) as ReceivedDate
        FROM @CostTable R1
        JOIN History H1 
        ON R1.VehicleID=H1.VehicleID 
        AND H1.ReceivedDate < R1.RepairDate
        GROUP BY R1.RepairDate;
    RETURN;
END;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot use dynamic SQL in functions, it will be better to turn it into a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetCostData(@CostTable VARCHAR(30)) 
AS
BEGIN 
  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000) =
  N'SELECT R1.Repairdate, Max(H1.ReceivedDate) as ReceivedDate
    FROM ' + @CostTable + N'R1
    JOIN History H1 
    ON R1.VehicleID=H1.VehicleID 
    AND H1.ReceivedDate < R1.RepairDate
    GROUP BY R1.RepairDate'

    EXEC (@sql)
END
```

---

To use the result of this stored proc, you should insert the results into a temp table and then join to this temp table. See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3b96f/6).

```
create table table1(id int, Repairdate datetime)

insert into table1 values (1, getdate())

go

create procedure GetCostData
as
begin
  select getdate() as Repairdate, getdate() as ReceivedDate
end

go

create table #temp(Repairdate datetime, ReceivedDate datetime)

insert into #temp
exec getcostdata

select * from table1 t1
inner join #temp t
on cast(t1.Repairdate as date) = cast(t.Repairdate as date)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't turn it into a SP, because I'm using it in a query.

Comment: In what way are you using it in the query?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19751718/three-tables-sql-query/20260641?noredirect=1#comment30255131_20260641